# HTTP status code 406 on one server, not on another

Tags: http, http-error

I built a java application that uses Apache's HttpClient, and I am only doing this:

```
HttpGet getRequest = new HttpGet("http://whois.arin.net/rest/ip/...");

getRequest.addHeader("accept", "application/json");

HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(getRequest);

response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode() ---> returns 200 and 406
```

When I run on my local Mac, it works fine, when I run on my companies network, I get a '406'.
Why would it run fine locally and not on my companies network?

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that your company has an intercepting proxy, which inspects http traffic in and out. The proxy will likely want to examine actual request/response bodies. In this case, the proxy does not understand `application/json` in your request, so it refuses to let it pass through.